Coldfusion CFFile
Can I ask for assistance with understanding how file lock
What happens if two calls happen occur simultaneously? Will an exception be thrown because temp1.txt is lock?
I couldn't find any reference in the documentation.

If you are using CFLOCK to lock the file, the short answer is that this should never happen.
Regarding the temp1.txt lock exception, this is more than likely that the file is being used by another process, and thus is being prevented from access. This can happen if the file is being used by another app, or the previous CF request did not release the lock correctly.
